# probability regarding three people throwing a die

Tags: probability

There are 3 players, A, B, C, taking turns to roll a die in the order ABCABC....

What's the probability of A is the first to throw a 6, B is the second, and C is the third?

The answer said it's 216/1001, but I always got 125/1001

The way I did it was:
Let $X_1$= number of rolls till A throw a 6
    $X_2$= number of rolls till B throw a 6
    $X_3$= number of rolls till C throw a 6
$P(X_1=i)=\frac{1}{6} (\frac{5}{6})^{i-1}$
$P(X_2=j)=\frac{1}{6} (\frac{5}{6})^{j-1}$
$P(X_3=k)=\frac{1}{6} (\frac{5}{6})^{k-1}$
therefore, $P$(A is the first to throw a 6, B is the second, and C is the third)
$=P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3)  $
= $\sum_{i<j<k}^{  } (\frac{1}{6})^3 (\frac{5}{6} )^{(i-1)+(j-1)+(k-1)}  $
$= (\frac{1}{6})^3 \sum_{i<j}^{  } (\frac{5}{6} )^{(i-1)+(j-1)} \sum_{k=j+1}^{\infty } (\frac{5}{6} )^{k-1}  $
$ = (\frac{1}{6})^3 \sum_{i<j}^{  } (\frac{5}{6} )^{(i-1)+(j-1)} \frac{(\frac{5}{6})^{j}} {1-\frac{5}{6}} $
$ =(\frac{1}{6})^2 \sum_{i<j}^{  } (\frac{5}{6} )^{(i-1)+(j-1)+j}$
$ =(\frac{1}{6})^2 \sum_{i}^{  }(\frac{5}{6} )^{(i-1)}\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty}  (\frac{5}{6} )^{2j-1}$
$ =(\frac{1}{6})^2 \sum_{i}^{  }(\frac{5}{6} )^{(i-1)} \frac{(\frac{5}{6})^{2i+1}} {1-\frac{5}{6}} $
$ =(\frac{1}{6}) \sum_{i}^{  }(\frac{5}{6} )^{(i-1)+2i+1}$
$ =(\frac{1}{6}) \sum_{i=1}^{\infty  }(\frac{5}{6} )^{3i}$
$=\frac{125}{546}$

Could anyone help me check where went wrong? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they go in the order A,B,C, you want $\sum_{i\le j\le k}$.

**Detail:** We want $$\sum_{0\le i\le j\le k}(5/6)^i(5/6)^j(5/6)^k(1/6)^3.$$
Summing from $k=j$ to $\infty$, we get
$$\sum_{0\le i\le j}(1/6)^2(5/6)^i (5/6)^{2j}.$$
The summation with respect to $j$ yields
$$\sum_{0\le i} (5/6)^{3i},$$
which is $\frac{6^3}{(11)(91)}$.

Comment: May I ask why it's the case $i \le j \le k$? Thank you~~

Comment: If for example $i=j$, say both equal to $3$, then B got her $6$ on her third toss, and so did A. But A's third toss came before B's, so A got her $6$ before B did.

Comment: Hi Andre, so would $X_1$ still be the number of rolls till A throw a 6? I thought the variable set up was, if I labeled each roll, A(1)B(2)C(3)A(4)B(5)C(6)A(7)B(8)C(9)....,if A and B got 6 on their second turn, and A got 6 on the 4th, and B got 6 on the 5th, and that's why I though it should be i<j<k case? Thank you!

Comment: If the probabilities are to be the ones you listed, we have separate counters for A, B, C.

Comment: How to set up the variable if the counters are separated? I cannot think of a second way to define $X_1, X_2,X_3$ as I did in the beginning. Thanks a lot~~

Comment: I am reluctant to write out the details, the typesetting is not fun, and summing series, though it will give an answer, is not a best approach. Maybe later.

Comment: Oh, I mean, if I'd like to count A,B,C separately, what is the set up of $X_1, X_2, X_3$ would it be? thank you!!

Comment: Do you want me to do the problem along the lines I suggested? I can write it out.

Comment: sorry I just saw your comment here. Yes, could you write it out for me if you have time? because I still cannot see the difference between $X_1<X_2<X_3$ and $X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3$ that would be under different set up...I think from my set up for $X_i$ in the beginning is for this case $X_1<X_2<X_3$, but the result of the calculation doesn't match the problem statement on the book, but with $X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3$ I did get the matched answer, and $X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3$ did make sense to me with your previous comment.Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid infinite sums altogether if you use a conditioning argument.

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ be the times of the first six for each of the three players.

We look at the two man game first. Let $q=\mathbb{P}(X_2<X_3)$. By first step analysis, we have
$q={1\over 6}+\left({5\over 6}\right)^2q$, so $q={6\over 11}$.

For the full three man game, let $p=\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3)$,
First step analysis gives $p={1\over 6}q+\left({5\over 6}\right)^3p$,
or ${91\over 216} p={1\over 11}$. Finally, this means $p={216\over 1001}$.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative that is a bit more intuitive, in a similar vein to that of @user940.

Consider events A, B, C where:
$$A=\{\text{the event that A is the first to roll a 6}\}$$
$$B=\{\text{the event that B is the second to roll a 6}\}$$
$$C=\{\text{the event that C is the third to roll a 6}\}$$

We know that the probability of the event of interest (A, B, and C occur) is given by:

$$P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(C|A\cap B) P(B|A)P(A) $$

$P(A)$ is the probability that A is the first to roll a six. Remember they are rolling in the order ABCABCABC...

$$P(A) = \frac{1}{6} ~+~ \bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^3\frac{1}{6} ~+~... = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{i=0}^n \bigg[\bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^3\bigg]^i = \frac{1}{6} \bigg(\frac{1}{1-(\frac{5}{6})^3} \bigg)=\frac{36}{91}$$

Now we can calculate $P(B|A)$, which is the probability that B is the second to roll a six after A has already rolled a six. They are now effectively rolling in the order A|BCBCBC... The probability can be calculated similarly:

$$P(B|A) = \frac{1}{6} ~+~ \bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^2\frac{1}{6} ~+~... = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{i=0}^n \bigg[\bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^2\bigg]^i = \frac{1}{6} \bigg(\frac{1}{1-(\frac{5}{6})^2} \bigg)=\frac{6}{11}$$

Finally, and most simply, $P(C|A\cap B)=1$, as the probability of C being the third to roll a six, after A and B already have, is 1.

Now we can multiply everything together:

$$P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(C|A\cap B) P(B|A)P(A) = 1*\frac{6}{11}*\frac{36}{91}=\frac{216}{1001}$$

[EDIT] Note that this problem can be generalized to any binary event with success probability p (which in this case is $\frac16$). The general answer should be:

$$P(A\cap B \cap C) = \frac{1}{(1+q+q^2)(1+q)}$$

where $q = 1-p$